# Missing params when save to postgres table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

All was well before changing my db schema

Before:

```
...
t.string :skills, :string
...
```

After:

```
...
  t.string :skills, array: true, default: '{}'
end

add_index :table_name, :skills, using: 'gin'
...
```

In log console I can see the params as:

```
"project"=>{"skills"=>"Wordpress,OpenCart,Magneto","Spree Commerce"}
```

This part I can't understand what's going on (still in console log):

```
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "projects"... ["skills", "{ordpress,\"OpenCart\",Magneto}"]
```

Why the "W", in Wordpress is chopped off? Where is "Spree Commerce"?

Do I need to add something else on the index column?

My controller has the standard permit `:skills` and nothing in model `project.rb`

Comment: You pass string `"Wordpress,OpenCart,Magneto","Spree Commerce"` instead of array `["Wordpress,OpenCart,Magneto","Spree Commerce"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am lazy, I have found a better route.

My project controller permit params was just the standard:

```
...

 def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(foo_params)
 end

 private
  def foo_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:a, :b, :skills)
  end
...
```

I'm not technical enough to know how to allow hash/array, so the lazy way is to:

```
...
def create
  par = (params["project"]["skills"]).split(",")
  @project = current_user.projects.build(foo_params.merge({"skills" => par}))
end

private
  def foo_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:a, :b)
  end
...
```

Now I have:

[image]

If you know a better way, please let me know. Thanks.